# Field name with dot in Json datasource using ireport

Tags: json, jasper-reports, datasource

My sample json file content

```
{
"FlightLog":{
    "FlightLog.crewMembers":[

    ],
    "destinationStationCode":"JPN",
    "FlightLog.destinationStationCode":"IND",
    "FlightLog.originStationCode":"IND",
    "FlightLog._lockVersion":"0",
    "FlightLog.flightNum":"123"
}
}
```

I want to get value for FlightLog.FlightLog.originStationCode.

for eg:
When i declare field name as below , i am getting the value "JPN"

```
<field name="FlightLog.destinationStationCode" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[FlightLog.destinationStationCode]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

Whereas if i declare field as below,

```
<field name="destinationStationCode" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[FlightLog.FlightLog.destinationStationCode]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

I am not getting any value for the above code.

I tried using

```
<field name="destinationStationCode" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[FlightLog[FlightLog.destinationStationCode]]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="destinationStationCode2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[FlightLog.FlightLog\\.destinationStationCode]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

How can i do this?

```
UPDATE
```

My jrxml is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Test" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="062e3e2d-b648-49c7-b4a5-1d3c4fbdfc6b">
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="FlightLog" class="java.lang.Object">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[FlightLog]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20" uuid="dc09b2c4-31b1-4458-8097-2e912e80b3a2"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FlightLog}.get("FlightLog.destinationStationCode")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I am not able to pass data to subreport, eg: I have a json like below,

```
"MaintLogResource":{
    "MaintLogResource._lockVersion":"0",
    "MaintLogResource.resource":[
                                 {
                                 "TEST" : "TEST1",
                                 "ResourceType.resourceTimeHours":3.0,
                                 "ResourceType.resourceDescription":"resourceDescription",
                                 "ResourceType.resourceCount":2,
                                 "ResourceType.resourceIdentifier":{
                                 "ResourceIdentifier.resourceIdentifier":"resourceIdentifier",
                                 "ResourceIdentifier.typeOfResourceIdentifier":"EQUIPMENT"
                                 }
                                 }
                                 ]
}
```

How do i pass it to sub report,

i tried like below,

```
((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("MaintLogResource")).subDataSource("MaintLogResource.resource")
```

But the above code is giving me error,

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
    Source text : ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("MaintLogResource")).subDataSource("MaintLogResource")
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:203)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:591)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:559)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:966)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:392)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:294)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:455)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2044)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:778)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:288)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:151)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:126)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:464)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:300)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:757)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:1003)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: No node available. Iterate or rewind the data source.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource.subDataSource(JsonDataSource.java:445)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource$subDataSource$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at Logbook_1434518442194_713295.evaluate(calculator_Logbook_1434518442194_713295:311)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:190)
    ... 19 more
```

How can i pass data to subreport?

**UPDATE3**

I am able to pass data to sub report like below,

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource(new ByteArrayInputStream($F{MaintLogResource}.get("MaintLogResource.resource").toString().getBytes()), "")
```

when i read a key with "." i cannot get the value, whereas if the key without dot i'm able to read the value eg: i'm able to get value for the key "TEST" but not for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`destinationStationCode` is a key in `FlightLog` and hence it is directly accessible. Same rule is applied on other keys, until any key have period sign, like `FlightLog.destinationStationCode`, because period have its own meaning (access property on the object). And therefore it is not giving any value (You can verify by replacing period by any other characket, say "_", then all works).

To access this property, I suggest you to create an field `FlightLog` of type `Object`, like

```
<field name="FlightLog" class="java.lang.Object">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[FlightLog]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

and access its properties like

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="29" uuid="afa65308-c0ae-4375-b8e5-99af4b69e02e"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FlightLog}.destinationStationCode]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="29" width="555" height="29" uuid="2009cbd3-7fb7-4d9e-8067-b03937aefcaa"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FlightLog}.get("FlightLog.destinationStationCode")]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Hope this helps.

My files --

**JSON**

```
{
"FlightLog":{
    "FlightLog.crewMembers":[

    ],
    "destinationStationCode":"JPN",
    "FlightLog.destinationStationCode":"IND",
    "FlightLog.originStationCode":"IND",
    "FlightLog._lockVersion":"0",
    "FlightLog.flightNum":"123"
}
}
```

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="53cc1a16-1ec1-486c-82f6-51915fa4b069">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <field name="FlightLog" class="java.lang.Object">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[FlightLog]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="58" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="29" uuid="afa65308-c0ae-4375-b8e5-99af4b69e02e"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FlightLog}.destinationStationCode]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="29" width="555" height="29" uuid="2009cbd3-7fb7-4d9e-8067-b03937aefcaa"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FlightLog}.get("FlightLog.destinationStationCode")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Thanks, i am getting compilation error Compilation exceptions: com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.ErrorsCollector@260702ee net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file: 1. destinationStationCode cannot be resolved or is not a field                 value = ((java.lang.Object)field_FlightLog.getValue()).destinationStationCode; //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$ , also for get method

Comment: Can you provide your jrxml file?

Comment: I have added my jrxml file, have a look.

Comment: i have added my jrxml, btw if i create text field displaying FlightLog field it prints all the values inside that key

Comment: You xml is having the property language="groovy" which i don't need, because of that i am getting compilation error, is there a way do it using without groovy

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. I'll update you after trying once without groovy.

Comment: It is good, if you post your solution and accept that, so that it helps other developers.

Comment: Do you want to pass full json or a particular field?

Comment: i want to pass full json (MaintLogResource.resource)

Comment: i'm able to pass the data to subreport, how to create fields like you mentioned earlier, so that i can read keys with dot.